# JSF 2.2 How to sort datatable (show last item created first)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, datatable

HI I'm trying to sort my datatable so the last item created by the user appers as the first item in the table.

```xhtml
<h:outputText value="#{bean.pagination.pageFirstItem + 1}..#{bean.pagination.pageLastItem + 1}/#{bean.pagination.itemsCount}"/>
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.previous}" 
    value="#{bundle.Previous} #{bean.pagination.pageSize}" 
    rendered="#{bean.pagination.hasPreviousPage}"/>
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.next}" 
    value="#{bundle.Next} #{bean.pagination.pageSize}" 
    rendered="#{bean.pagination.hasNextPage}"/>

<h:dataTable value="#{metadata.placeholders}" var="placeholder">
    <h:column>
    .....
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Here's my pagination

public abstract class PaginationHelper {

```
private int pageSize;
private int page;

public PaginationHelper(int pageSize) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
}

public abstract int getItemsCount();

public abstract DataModel createPageDataModel();

public int getPageFirstItem() {
    return page * pageSize;
}

public int getPageLastItem() {
    int i = getPageFirstItem() + pageSize - 1;
    int count = getItemsCount() - 1;
    if (i > count) {
        i = count;
    }
    if (i < 0) {
        i = 0;
    }
    return i;
}

public boolean isHasNextPage() {
    return (page + 1) * pageSize + 1 <= getItemsCount();
}

public void nextPage() {
    if (isHasNextPage()) {
        page++;
    }
}

public boolean isHasPreviousPage() {
    return page > 0;
}

public void previousPage() {
    if (isHasPreviousPage()) {
        page--;
    }
}

public int getPageSize() {
    return pageSize;
}
```

This is how I use the pagination

```
public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
    if (pagination == null) {
        pagination = new PaginationHelper(5) {
            @Override
            public int getItemsCount() {
                return getFacade().count();
            }

            @Override
            public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
            }
        };
    }
    return pagination;
}
```

Comment: [DataModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) has 6 standard implementations in the Java EE 7 API and an unknown number in your particular stack. The answer depends on the data source.

Comment: @McDowell what do you mean the datasource? should I sort the results of the quey in the jpa layer?

Comment: @IgnacioGarat If this is a database-backed source then then sorting in the database is potentially better than sorting in the view. But it depends on your system architecture and the data sizes involved for the particular query.

Comment: @McDowell yes is mysql but I would like to have it sorted in the pagination, Im using jsf 2.2 with tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up doing the sorting with JPA.

```
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<Offer> e = cq.from(Offer.class);
    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(e.get("id")));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq.getResultList();
```